# Facebook, code for creating events for large grounds

Tags: facebook

A friend of mine is an Admin for a large Facebook group. Its a mountain biking group so we have regular planned rides.

In the beginning he could just invite everyone in the ground (not just friends) and we would all get a notification that a ride was on, all good.

But, the group now has more than 250 members, tbh only about 30 of us ride each week the other 220+ members just like to talk about bikes :)

The problem comes when trying to create the ride events as he can no longer just invite everyone he has to pick the people one by one from his own friend list.

Can this be done via code? I gut say not as I recon facebook check this server side

`// Only allow invitations to be sent to friends
if (memberList > 250) 
{`

Answer (score 0):

You cant invite via GrapAPI at all.

You can write a small js to tick all friends within the invite dialogue, but you will be blocked from invitation after doing this 2-3 times for quite a while.

To conclude the answer. No you can not invite via any Facebook API at all (except for games, but still not programmatically)

Comment: I didn't realise I tagged GraphAPI , I will remove that tag.

Comment: @SteveDrake There is only GraphAPI more or less available. You cant invite anyhow programmatically without violating Facebook's TOS.

Comment: I think, the idea is. If the group is large you just create an event and people can choose to join if they wish rather than spamming the entire group with invites. I will suggest this.